# Handling or disabling Sitecore field's validation during Runtime

Tags: validation, sitecore, sitecore-mvc, experience-editor

I have a custom field with a regex validation `^(?!\s*$).+`. For some reason this does not work in the Experience Editor.

Is there a way I can disable the validation if the page is being edited in the Experience Editor? In the Content Editor it should work the same. Is there a way to handle it in Runtime without actually editing the Field value?

I am currently using Sitecore 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug and as a workaround you can simply exclude the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ReturnFieldEditorValues.RegexValidate` processor from the `uiReturnFieldEditorValues` pipeline by commenting out the following line in your `Sitecore.config` file:

```
<processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ReturnFieldEditorValues.RegexValidate" />
```

This will disable the field validation on the *"OK"* button click within the *Edit* form and prevent the *Error message* pop-up appearing every time in the Experience Editor & blocking you from the field editing. But the field validation will remain triggered by the *"Save"* button click and the *"Error message"* pop-up will appear if any field does not match your regular expression.